# Dentro do ajax quero criar uma variável e usa-lá em vários lugares fora do ajax

Tags: ajax, async

Quero criar uma variável dentro do **ajax** e usa-lá em vários outros lugares, isto só funciona quando eu uso o `async:false` e sei que isto não é mais recomendado, como fazer isto de forma correta?

segue os códigos abaixo:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    // <![CDATA[
        $.ajax({
                 url: 'lista_empresas.txt',
                 //async:false,
                 cache: false,
                 dataType:"json",
                 success: function(retorno) {
                     empresa = retorno['empresa']
                     $('body').append(empresa)  
                 }
        });
        $('body').append('Minha empresa: ' + empresa)
    });
   // ]]>
 </script>
```

**JSON**

> {"empresa":"ATR Brasil","ramo_atividade":"transportes"}

Comment: você quer usar a variavel logo após o retorno do ajax? ou armazenar ela em uma variavel para ser usada futuramente por outra função?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trabalhar com promessas, um bom exemplo seria:

```
var request = function(link, parametros) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "https://baconipsum.com/api/" + link,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: parametros,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow) {
      console.log(textStatus);
    }
  });
};

request("?type=meat-and-filler").success(function(data) {
  console.log('executou 1');
  request("?type=all-meat&paras=2&start-with-lorem=1").success(function(data) {
    console.log('executou 2');
    request("?type=all-meat&sentences=1&start-with-lorem=1").success(function(data) {
      console.log('executou 3');
    });
  });
});
```

Exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/3da9aswq/4/)